# Обработка условий при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер

Есть программа на питоне, которая получает строку и парсит ее по спец. символу

```
clientMsg = format(message)

data = clientMsg

arr = data.split(';')

clientIP  = "Client IP :{}".format(address)
i = str(arr[4])
print(clientIP)
print  ("id", i)
if i == "1":
    t= str(arr[1])
    g = str(arr[2])
    bat = int(arr[3])
    b= bat
    csq = str(arr[5])
```

И, если, строка пришла в неправильном виде, то программа вылетает. 
Как реализовать парсинг, и если парсить не удалось  - просто вывести ошибку?

Comment: Ловить исключение?

Comment: я понимаю логически как это сделать но не знаю как сделать это программно_ недавно только наслан заниматься программированием

Comment: Закиньте ваш проблемный код в try:   catch:

Comment: если несложно, можно пример кода

Answer (score 0):

```
 try:
    clientMsg = format(message)

    data = clientMsg

    arr = data.split(';')

    clientIP = "Client IP :{}".format(address)
    i = str(arr[4])
    print(clientIP)
    print("id", i)
    if i == "1":
        t = str(arr[1])
        g = str(arr[2])
        bat = int(arr[3])
        b = bat
        csq = str(arr[5])
except Exception:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: не совсем понял

Comment: Что именно не понял?

Comment: извиняюсь все понятно

Comment: к сожалению не работает_ код кнутри true -не выполняется

Comment: он и раньше не работал, это пример как ловить ошибки